# SFDMU timeout during insert

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, sfdmu

I'm running SFDMU to upsert data (roughly 120k records).  During the middle of a run, the process stopped with the below message.  Is there any sort of fix for this (other than reducing the size of the upsert, which isn't a great solution for me)?  I found a post on the site, but it's not the answer I'm hoping for: https://help.sfdmu.com/troubleshooting/plugin-wont-run/read-econnreset-error-during-retrieving-the-source-data.
A related issue: the log below notes some failed records.  However when it times-out, it doesn't update the file in the target directory, so I'm not able to see what the issues were.
Thanks for your help!
chris

```
[10:56:44.623] [Batch# 7503S000000ndYjQAI:Insert] {Station_ID_to_Zip_Assignment__c} Processing ... 22000 records processed, 400 records failed.
[10:56:53.855] [Batch# 7503S000000ndYjQAI:Insert] {Station_ID_to_Zip_Assignment__c} Processing ... 23000 records processed, 400 records failed.
[10:56:59.291] [Batch# 7503S000000ndYjQAI:Insert] {Station_ID_to_Zip_Assignment__c} Processing ... 23600 records processed, 400 records failed.
[10:57:03.866] [Batch# 7503S000000ndYjQAI:Insert] {Station_ID_to_Zip_Assignment__c} Processing ... 23800 records processed, 600 records failed.
[10:57:09.128] [Batch# 7503S000000ndYjQAI:Insert] {Station_ID_to_Zip_Assignment__c} Processing ... 24000 records processed, 600 records failed.      
[10:57:09.150] [ERROR] {Station_ID_to_Zip_Assignment__c} The Insert API operation has been failed. Error message: connect ETIMEDOUT 140.17.239.79:443.
Command in progress... done
 
[10:57:09.169] [ERROR] Error during execution of the command: {Station_ID_to_Zip_Assignment__c} The Insert API operation has been failed..
[10:57:09.174] [ERROR] Execution of the command sfdmu:run has been completed. Exit code 4 (COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR).
[10:57:09.180] Total time elapsed: 00h 10m 41s 344ms .
```

Answer (score 0):

Try decreasing the batch size in the export file and if it still doesn't work, set parallel jobs to 2.

{
"bulkApiV1BatchSize" : 1000,
"parallelBulkJobs" : 2
}